# JS Link SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, jslink

I'm trying to implement JS Link on SharePoint 2013. However, I can't seem to make it work.

Uploaded a sample `.js` file in Site Assets with a simple alert message.

```
<script> alert("test") </script>
```

1. Hit on Edit Page.
2. Selected edit web part.
3. And reference the file in Site Assets.

[image]

Did I miss a step?

Comment: Try to give a full URL to your .js file it will anyhow convert it to relative URL once you save the web part properties window.

Comment: I did, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Something is wrong with your URL:

1. If you have placed your JS inside `SiteAssets` library of some CHILD site, you should use `~site/SiteAssets/...` url.
2. If you have placed your JS inside `SiteAssets` library of root site of site collection, you should use `~sitecollection/SiteAssets/...` url.

Anyway, you can always try with absolute URL of the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but in case someone bumps into it
You should get rid of the  tags.

Replace

```
<script> alert("test") </script>
```

with

```
alert("test");
```

amd use `~site/SiteAssets/sample.js or ~sitecollection/SiteAssets/sample.js` as mentioned above by ECMAD

Answer (score 0):

I published a Step-by-Step guide on [How to upload .js files and link it to a list in 9 Steps (de/en)](https://blog.afrait.com/how-to-upload-js-files-and-link-it-to-a-list-9-steps/)

In this guide I placed the .js file into the masterpage gallery. Maybe it will help you out a little bit.

Comment: Can't seem to access the link.

Comment: For me, it's working. Do you still have problems to open the link?